# Android : Drawable next to TextView with weight to each TextView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve the result as shown in Pic1. Tried setting gravity, paddingleft etc but the drawable image comes in the right end and not next to Text(SHown in Pic 2[image]). Can anyone suggest how to align the image next to TextView? Also how to set the size of drawable?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="@drawable/separator"
    android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sms"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/message"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/message"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:text="SMS" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/call"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/call"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/call"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="CALL" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/mail"
    android:drawablePadding="3dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/mail"
    android:text="MAIL" />
```

Comment: Weight to textview forces it occupy the whole width hence the drwable is placed to the dead end of the textview

Comment: Use drawableLeft and set the image... Give drawablePadding.. it will be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a custom button which doesnt require layout nestings and can align drawable images as required.

**Layout file button.xml:**

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    style="@style/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

**Custom Button Class:**

```
public class DrawableAlignedButton extends RelativeLayout {

  private View view;
  private Button button;

  /**
   * @param context
   *          used to inflate the View.
   * @param attrs
   *          XML defined attributes.
   */
  public DrawableAlignedButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  /**
   * @param context
   *          used to inflate the View.
   */
  public DrawableAlignedButton(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
  }

  /**
   * @param context
   *          used to inflate the View.
   * @param attrs
   *          XML defined attributes.
   * @param style
   *          the style for the View.
   */
  public DrawableAlignedButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int style) {
    super(context, attrs, style);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  private void init(final Context context, final AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    view = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button, this, true);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_button);

    String buttonText = null;
    int drawableStart = 0;
    int drawableEnd = 0;

    if (attributeSet != null) {
      final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CustomButtonStyle, 0, 0);
      buttonText = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomButtonStyle_buttonText);
      drawableStart = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomButtonStyle_buttonDrawableStart, 0);
      drawableEnd = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomButtonStyle_buttonDrawableEnd, 0);
      a.recycle();
    }

    FontUtil.getInstance(context).useNormalRegularFont(button);

    if (buttonText != null) {
      button.setText(buttonText);
    }

    button.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableStart, 0, drawableEnd, 0);
  }

  /**
   * Sets the button text.
   * 
   * @param text
   *          the text to be set.
   */
  public void setButtonText(final String text) {
    if (button != null) {
      button.setText(text);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the drawable to the button.
   * 
   * @param drawableStart
   *          the drawable to set at the beginning of the text.
   * @param drawableEnd
   *          the drawable to set at the end of the text.
   */
  public void setDrawableStart(final int drawableStart, final int drawableEnd) {
    if (button != null) {
      button.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableStart, 0, drawableEnd, 0);
    }
  }

}
```

**How to use it in the XML :**

```
<com.package.view.DrawableAlignedButton
        xmlns:drawableAlignedButton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_button_selector"
        drawableAlignedButton:buttonDrawableStart="@drawable/small_active"
        drawableAlignedButton:buttonText="Button Text" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to build around this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/message"
            android:text="SMS" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/call"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CALL" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/mail"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MAIL" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Initially I thought of doing it in this way but to avoid layout nestings tried without nested linearlayout. I will use your code for getting the result. Is there any way I can change the size of drawable?

Comment: Size of drawable set to textview programatically u mean?

Comment: Tab layout is the better approach than this

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu I meant size of drawable in the xml itself.

Comment: Nope i dont think so you can.. instead change your drawable size itself. with various densities

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that, you are setting the layoutWidth=0dp and weight 1. This makes every TextView take maximum width according to the weight. The drawableRight/drawableEnd sets the drawable resource to be drawn at the rightmost edge of the view. If you want to keep this layout just wrap it in another viewGroup like @Dhinakaran has shown. Better approach would be to use a **tab layout**.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple Linear Layouts, you can use a Relative Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]